# Django reverse page object numeration

Tags: django, reverse, paginator

I use `{{ forloop.counter0|add:page_obj.start_index }}`
And get (pagination 3):

```
Page1: 1  Page2: 4
       2         5
       3
```

If I use `{{ forloop.revcounter0|add:page_obj.start_index }}`
I get:

```
Page1: 3  Page2: 5
       2         4
       1
```

How can I get:

```
Page1: 5  Page2: 2
       4         1
       3
```

I was thinking something like `{{ paginator.count|add:SOMETHING }}`

Comment: Share your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) to do this. In some suitable app of yours make a directory `templatetags.py` and also add a file `__init__.py` in it. Inside directory make a new file in which we will write template tags lets say `pagination_extras.py`. After this your directory structure would look something like:

```
<appname>/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        pagination_extras.py
    views.py
```

Now in `pagination_extras.py` make a custom template tag to do this calculation for you:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def pagination_reverse_numbering(paginator, page_obj, loop_count):
    return paginator.count - page_obj.start_index() - loop_count + 1
```

Now in your template you will first load this tag and then use it to perform your numbering:

```
{% load pagination_extras %}
...
{% for item in page_obj %}
    {% pagination_reverse_numbering paginator page_obj forloop.counter0 %}
{% endfor %}
```